# How to implement Dijkstras Algorithm with Adjacency lists

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra, adjacency-list

My program is reading input from a text file in the order of

```
A
B 
C

A B 10
A C 5
B A 3
B C 2
C A 4
C B 1
```

and stores the data into a graph which is represented by an adjacency list. I want to write a program that finds the shortest path from A to all other nodes using Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I have watched several videos but still couldn't quite get how to implement the algorithm as the examples use graphs which are represented as adjacency matrices. Below is the program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define INFINITE -1

/* node */
struct Node
{
    char key;
    int distance;
    Node *next;
};

/* GraphNode */
struct GraphNode
{
    char key;
    Node *listpointer;
};

/* Add nodes to the front of the list */
void AddNodeToFront(Node*& listpointer, char newkey, int newdistance)
{
   Node *temp;
   temp = new Node;
   temp->key = newkey;
   temp->distance=newdistance;
   temp->next = listpointer;
   listpointer = temp;
}

/* printf LLnodes */
void PrintLLnodes(Node*& listpointer)
{
    Node *temp;
    temp = listpointer;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("to node %c dist: %d \n", temp->key, temp->distance);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
 }

/* Implement the Graph class  */
class Graph
{
    private:
        vector<GraphNode> adjlist;
        int totalgraphnodes;
    public:
        Graph(){totalgraphnodes = 0;}
        ~Graph(){}
        void AddNewGraphNode(char newgraphnode);
        void AddNewEdgeBetweenGraphNodes(char A, char B, int distance);
        void PrintAllGraphNodesWithCosts();
        void DijkstrasAlgorithm(char sourcenode);
        int GetTotalNodes() { return totalgraphnodes; }
};

/* graph class functions */
void Graph::AddNewGraphNode(char newgraphnode){
    totalgraphnodes++;
    GraphNode temp;
    temp.key=newgraphnode;
    temp.listpointer = NULL;//important
    adjlist.push_back(temp);
}

void Graph::AddNewEdgeBetweenGraphNodes(char A, char B, int distance)
{
     //find which node A is
     int a;
     for (a = 0;adjlist.size();a++)
     {
         if (A == adjlist[a].key) break;
     }
     AddNodeToFront(adjlist[a].listpointer, B, distance);
}

void Graph::PrintAllGraphNodesWithCosts()
{
     for (unsigned int a = 0;a < adjlist.size();a++){
         printf("From Node %c: \n", adjlist[a].key);
         PrintLLnodes(adjlist[a].listpointer);
     }  
}

**// implement Dijkstra's Algorithm
void Graph::DijkstrasAlgorithm(char sourcenode)**
{
    int distance[adjlist.size()];
    char state[adjlist.size()];

    // setting the initial distance and state of the first node
    distance[0] = 0;
    state[0] = 'p';

    // assigning all distance and state to temp and infinite
    for(int i = 1; i <= adjlist.size(); i++)
    {
        distance[i] = INFINITE;
        state[i] = 't';
    }

    // get the sourcenode from the adjlist in Graph
    unsigned int a;
    for(a = 0; a <= adjlist.size(); a++)
    {
        if(sourcenode == adjlist[a].key) { break; } // break when found 'A'
    }

    // assign sourcenode listpointer to current
    Node *current;
    current = adjlist[a].listpointer;

    bool stilltempvertex = true;
    while(stilltempvertex) {}   
}

/* declare a new Graph */
Graph mygraph;
main( /*int argc, char** argv */)
{ 

    /* call Dijkstra  */
    mygraph.DijkstrasAlgorithm('A'); //always from A in this program

    /* Print answer in the required format */
}
```

As far as implementation is concerned, all the nodes and edges are read correctly (I have ommited some code to allow for readability, but mygraph has nodes A, B, C and the corresponding edges.), its just that I cant seem to figure out how to properly implement the algorithm for this one.

The nodes are readfrom the file and stored in a vector ajdlist. Each graphnode then has its own linked list which points to adjacent nodes in the graph.

Anyone could take me step by step through with the algorithm implementation on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those videos you were watching could have shown to use [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) instead of trying to create a home-made linked list.

Comment: You know how to iterate through an adjacency matrix, looking for edges from node X. You know how to iterate through node X's list of adjacent nodes. What's the problem?

Comment: Also, please choose a language, either `C` or `C++`.  Your code uses `C++`, thus remove the `C` tag or rewrite the code using `C` and remove the `C++` tag.

Comment: for the future, note that the only good reason to use adj.matrix instead of adj.list is either floyd-warshall algorithm or a very dense graph